# How am I accessing the cpp standard library without placing '#include' statements?

Tags: c++, macos, header, include

I've been teaching myself cpp sporadically from 'accelerated C++' and recently I noticed that when I forgot my `#include <algorithm>` statement, my code (which includes transform and find_if) compiled and ran successfully anyways. After this, I tried removing all standard header include statements altogether and found that my code still ran.

I assume my inability to understand preprocessor commands will be resolved by the time I finish the book, but for now I just need to know how to make sure that my terminal yells at me when I make the header improperly so I can learn where things are located in the std library.

I am running OS 10.6.5 so I have to compile my code with the following unix exe file:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall
PROG = TrainingProject23

SRCS = TrainingProject23.cpp

ifeq ($(shell uname),Darwin)
    LIBS = -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT
else
    LIBS = -lglut
endif

all: $(PROG)

$(PROG):    $(SRCS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(PROG) $(SRCS) $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(PROG)
```

it includes the build protocol for OpenGL because I am learning that as well and it easy enough to use this file to compile all my C++ projects. I don't really understand the Makefile besides how to change the src file and program name, I just got it off the internet.

Comment: Not enough information. We need TrainingProject23.cpp

Comment: Hmm... TrainingProject23 is just a file I keep open so I don't have to modify the above unix file very much (I get to keep SRCS = TrainingProjects23 the same from project to project). I frequently delete the contents completely and start over to try something new. I no longer have the contents, but every code I've tried in it yields the same results: it runs and compiles successfully regardless of whether or not the necessary standard library nodes have been included.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard library headers are allowed to include other standard library headers. So if you e.g. `#include <string>`; your implementation is allowed (but not required to) include every other standard library header there is, including `<algorithm>`. In your case, that probably happened, but it's nothing you should rely on.

Comment: In C++, that is generally true (as in, any one C++ standard header can drag in others).  In pure Standard C, that is not the case; one standard header is not allowed to pull in others - except for one specific special case: `<inttypes.h>` can include `<stdint.h>`.  In POSIX, some headers are allowed to include some others.

Comment: @Jonathan - good point. He could have had non-standard-headers as well, though.

Comment: AHA! I did not know this! This was definitely the problem. In fact, I'm pretty sure the <string> <algorithm> example you provided was the exact scenario where I noticed it. Thanks to all who commented!

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to know for sure without seeing your exact code, but one possible option is that you are including other header files (Kristopher in comments is guessing OpenGL and/or GLUT) which in turn include the libraries your code didn't include explicitly.

E.g.

```
# File: my_incl.h
#include <algorithm>

# File: main.c
#include "my_incl.h"
# yay - you just included the algorithm.h without even trying.
```

Please note that this works, but relying on it is Bad Practice, for a variety of reasons:

- If your project stops including "my_incl.h", it will suddenly stop compiling, without 100% immediately obvious cause.
- It makes the code harder to read/understand since a list of includes allows you a quick summary of which libraries are used by your code.
- It's Just Sloppy

Comment: As an aside, this is often used in golfing: include a header with a short name which includes the ones we're interested in.

Comment: To expand on this: You are probably including OpenGL and/or GLUT header files, and they are probably including standard library headers.

Comment: @marcog - my days of golfing in C (as opposed to Perl) are waaaaaay past but good tip to know, thanks!